# How should I send file to api server in laravel by Guzzle Client

Tags: api, file-upload, upload, guzzle

Could you please tell me how should I send a file to upload on api?

In api server we have a post method which it gives two parameters:
one `name` in query and a file in `formData` then it gives a link as response body.
I'm going to send file via guzzle client in this format:

```
$file = $request->file('InputFile');
$file_path = $file->getPathname();
$response = $this->CX_Client->post('/file/upload?name='.$fileName, [
                'formData' =>
                [
                    'file' =>
                    [
                            'name'     => 'InputFile',
                            'contents' => fopen($file_path, 'r'),
                            'filename' => $fileName
                    ]

                ]
            ]);
```

But this does not work and server can not find its parameters in this request.  What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `multipart` instead of `formData`

https://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart

```
$response = $this->CX_Client->post('/file/upload?name='.$fileName, [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'foo',
            'contents' => 'data',
            'headers'  => ['X-Baz' => 'bar']
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'baz',
            'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r')
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'qux',
            'contents' => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
            'filename' => 'custom_filename.txt'
        ],
    ]
]);
```